# Java error line number not being reported and debugging not allowed

Tags: java, itext

I have a Java project where I'm using iText 2.1.7 (a pretty old version, I know, but it's a legacy project) to some PDF files. I've created a test like follows in order to tune and debug some font-related issues:

```
@Test
public void testGeneratePDF() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
    document.open();

    String fontPath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("NotoSansCJK.ttc").getPath();
    FontFactory.register(fontPath);

    Set<String> fonts = new TreeSet<String>(FontFactory.getRegisteredFonts());
    for (String fontname : fonts) {
        showFontInfo(document, fontname);
    }

    document.close();
}
```

And when I run the test, I get the following error trace:

> ExceptionConverter: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException: /Users/jdebenitocalzada/dev/myproject/target/test-classes/NotoSansCJK.ttc is not a valid TTF file.

```
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.EnumerateTTC.findNames(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.EnumerateTTC.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.enumerateTTCNames(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.FontFactoryImp.register(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.register(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.register(Unknown Source)
at com.mycompany.myproject.PDFGenerationTest.testGeneratePDF(PDFGenerationTest.java:37)
at ...
```

As you can see above, there's no information about line numbers where each error was thrown under com.lowagie.text package classes. In addition, I've tried to debug the code in IntelliJ but the debugger doesn't stop at the library code (it does at my own project code).

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: this explains the base problem, why not just using a valid TTF file? NotoSansCJK.ttc is not a valid TTF file? Even if you could debug, that wouldn't change anything. It's probably because you don't have the actual code of that library in your IDE, just a "decompiled" version, which isn't in sync with what is executed

Comment: The point is that the library also supports TTC files, and that's one of the reasons why I would like to debug it. In addition, I downloaded from Github the source code of the library for the very same version I'm using in my project, so I can't understand why I can't debug it.

Comment: You should also download the sources jar. If you are using Maven then the tool can do this for you. I just checked on Maven Central, there is a sources jar for iText 2.1.7.

Comment: You have this as part of your path: `target/test-classes` which is typically IntelliJ. I don't think you use Maven, because then you would have `src/test/resources` somewhere in your path. So I don't know how to help you, I'm sure there's documentation on the IntelliJ website.

Comment: *"I downloaded from Github the source code of the library for the very same version I'm using in my project, so I can't understand why I can't debug it."* - most likely the itext 2.1.7 jar in your class path had been compiled without debug information. Thus, you cannot debug it. As you have the sources, simply complete then again *with debug information* and use that new jar instead of your original one.